# Erro de sintaxe javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Me deparei com o seguinte erro de sintaxe no javascript/jquery

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

e estou usando o plugin **Number.prototype.formatMoney** será que pode ter alguma coisa relacionada?

**Plugin**

```
Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(c, d, t){
var n = this, 
    c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c, 
    d = typeof d == "undefined" ? "." : d, 
    t = typeof t == "undefined" ? "," : t, 
    s = n < 0 ? "-" : "", 
    i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "", 
    j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
   return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
 };
```

**Chamando método**

```
$("#dados #total").html("R$ "+(parseFloat(total)).formatMoney(2, ',', '.'));
```

Sabem como resolver?

Comment: Cara, eu criei um fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/1dqhqu4s/) com seu código e ele funciona sem problemas. É muito provável que o problema esteja em outro local, poderia incluir mais um pouco do seu código?

Comment: @EdgarMunizBerlinck o código é muito grande, vou ver alguns trechos prováveis que possam estar com erro, mas você sabe especificamente o porque acontece esse erro `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number` ? se você também puder dar algum exemplo de ocasião em que acontece esse erro, agradeço :)

Comment: Cara, isso é erro de sintaxe mesmo. Veja o EDIT da minha resposta. Se não ajudar grita ai.

Answer (score 4):

Respondendo especificamente a sua pergunta: **Não**. Seu código em questão funciona sem problemas.

Prova: http://jsfiddle.net/1dqhqu4s/

Dado o trecho abaixo:

```
$("#dados #total").html("R$ "+(parseFloat(total)).formatMoney(2, ',', '.'));
```

Independente do valor da variável **total** o código funciona sem problemas.

A única coisa que poderia lhe causar problemas seria a variável **total** não estar definida, mas isso só daria problemas caso você estiver usando o **strict mode**. Além do mais o erro seria outro e não este que você nos relatou.

**EDIT**
Este erro em questão pode estar sendo causado por um erro na sintaxe do seu código mesmo. Provavelmente você não fechou uma chave, colchete ou parentese; Esqueceu um ponto e virgula ou coisa do tipo.

Comment: Pode ser erro na variável total mesmo, porque quando eu entro com um usuário funciona normal mas quando entro com outro acontece esse erro

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha Cara, esse erro ai é **true** bicho. Dá uma olhada com mais calma no seu código que deve ter alguma zica. Toma um café antes.

Comment: Valeu pela dica do café kk, vou dar uma olhada sim e depois posto a solução quando encontrar.. Valeu `+1`